# How to insert into table with PHP value.PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

In my php code, two ways,

`('#201707',$cont_array[$i],'N')` or `('#201707','$cont_array[$i]','N')` failed during insert into table `hpc_review`

```
$transmit_next="<input  value='allDel' type='button'><br>John<br>snow<br>stack<br>";
$cont_array = explode("<br>", $transmit_next);
for($i=1;$i<count($cont_array);$i++)
{
    $query="insert into hpc_review (sysnum,handler,stat) values ('#201707',$cont_array[$i],'N');";
    $stat = $conn->query($query);
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Can you include the error please?

Comment: I made mistake. In hpc_review,handler is int ,but  cont_array[$i] is var

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is:

```
  $query="insert into hpc_review (sysnum,handler,stat) values ('#201707','".$cont_array[$i]."','N');";
```

Comment: I made mistake. In hpc_review,handler is int ,but cont_array[$i] is var .

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$query="insert into hpc_review (sysnum,handler,stat) values ('#201707','" . $cont_array[$i] . "','N');";
```

But should use MySQLi driver and prepared statements, see: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 0):

IF $cont_array[$i] is a string :

```
 $query="insert into hpc_review (sysnum,handler,stat) values ('#201707','{$cont_array[$i]}','N');";
```

if $cont_array[$i] is integer like ID:

```
 $query="insert into hpc_review (sysnum,handler,stat) values ('#201707',{$cont_array[$i]},'N');";
```